# Command-line interface helpers?

Tags: ruby

I am working on a command-line interface to make my code more user-friendly. It currently looks like this:

```
loop do
  print "> "
  cmd = gets.chomp
  break  if cmd == "quit"
  run_command(cmd)
  puts
end
```

I would like to extend it a little bit to save typing. For example, I'd like to allow using the "Up Arrow" key to repeat the last command, and the "Tab" key to auto-match command etc.

Is there any tool to ease the job?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Might I add that [Trollop](https://github.com/ManageIQ/trollop) is good for command line arguments, if you need that as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for [readline](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/readline/rdoc/Readline.html), here's an example:

```
require "readline"

while cmd = Readline.readline("> ", true)
  break if cmd == "quit"
  run_command(cmd)
  puts
end
```

Tab-completion is a little trickier, though. Have a look at the [example on their documentation page](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/readline/rdoc/Readline.html#method-c-completion_proc-3D-label-Completion+for+a+Static+List).

Answer (score 0):

The library you are looking for is [readline](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/readline/rdoc/Readline.html)